# How to add more than 50000 record in excel file using microsoft graphapi

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, power-automate, excel-online

I have power automate which is creating excel file and exporting the sql query data into excel file. To export the data, i am using graph api excel connector. The graph api query is failing if file size exceeded 4 MB. How can i export the data using batch concept in power automate.

Comment: Do you use Excel Online (OneDrive) or Excel Online (Business)? Probably share your power automate code if possible.

Comment: You’ll need to batch up the calls.

Comment: Excel online(OneDrive)

Comment: there is no code, it is just query.https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/@{substring(outputs('Get_file_metadata')?['body/Id'], add(indexOf(outputs('Get_file_metadata')?['body/Id'], '.'),1))}/workbook/tables/FATable/rows/add